# iphone page curl option

Tags: iphone, page-curl

I need page curl option for my ebook reader just like iBooks by Apple. For that i got leaves project.I studied that project but its quite difficult for me learn since am a new bee :-). Can anyone of you please explain that page flipping code.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: we worked for weeks getting that stuff to work - please state a specific question

Comment: okay i need to implement that within 2 days. Can u please just tell me any other simple solution.

Comment: could u plz come for chat(iphone chat room)or else conduct me at renuga@i-waves.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent about 9 days and lots of math for implementing that, however it was more sophisticated then in iBooks. Here is very nice solution, but less interactive then in iBooks. You can play with it [link](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html)